# Intersection not merging enums for property

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create an intersection type in *Typescript v2.9.1* where both types have a given property, but of different types:
`const newItems: A[] & B[] = [];`

Given the following interfaces:

```
export interface A {
    category: EnumA;
}

export interface B {
    category: EnumB;
}

export enum EnumA {
    bar
}

export enum EnumB {
    foo
}
```

`EnumA` and `EnumB` have different values associated with them and I want to be aware of all of those values in a collection.

However if I try to do something like a filter:
`const filteredItems = newItems.filter(i => i.category !== EnumB.foo);`

I'm recieving a syntax error stating `Operator '!==' cannot be applied to types 'A' and 'EnumB.foo'` and the type of `i.category` is listed as `EnumA` in intellisense.

I would expect Typescript understand the type of `i.category` to be `EnumA & EnumB`. Is this a bug or do I have unreasonable expectations?

Comment: `newItems` can contain instances of `A` or `B` ?

Comment: Yes, it can. In reality, they're mostly identical with a few separate properties.

Comment: Seems like you want `(A | B)[]`, not `A[] & B[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need not an intersection of arrays (`A[] & B[]`, as you've written), because it means "this must have all the properties of `Array<A>`, and then all the properties of `Array<B>`, *which wasn't listed here before*". And since the sets of properties are identical (they are just differently typed), all of them is taken from `Array<A>`.

The code you used would compile if you write it as following:

```
const newItems: (A & B)[] = [];
const filteredItems = newItems.filter(i => i.category !== EnumB.foo);
```

since now the `newItems` is typed as an "array of things, each of them is both `A` and `B`". Their `category` property is `enum`, i.e. just `object`, and so can be merged. Then, we'll have it as `enumA & enumB`.

Comment: I would have gone for `(A|B)[]` since it can be either or.

Comment: @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir I see, but for now we have too little information to choose between two. For such a small code base both cases work equally well, so I decided not to go far from OP's variant. Perhaps if we had more complicated example, we would see the difference.